# Is an Azure DevOps build pipeline, is there a way to cancel one pipeline job from another job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline which contains two Agent Jobs, which I'll call Job A and Job B. I want these jobs to run simultaneously, but if Job A fails, then I don't need Job B to run to completion.

Is there any way to add a task to Job A which will cancel Job B (or, alternately, terminate the entire pipeline with a "Failed" status) if any of Job A's tasks failed?

Answer (score 6):

Add a PowerShell task that cancel the pipeline when a task failed:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   Write-Host "Cancel all jobs..."
   $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/$($env:BUILD_BUILDID)?api-version=2.0"
    $header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }
    $body = @{ 'status'='Cancelling' } | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Body $body -Headers $header -ContentType application/json
  displayName: Cancel the pipeline
  condition: failed()
  env:
       System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So this is super close to doing what I'd hoped, but unfortunately, it leaves the overall pipeline run with the "Cancelled" status rather than "Failed", which is a specific requirement for my case. Do you know if there's any way to cancel the pipeline's job(s)  through the REST API, but let the overall pipeline finish with the "Failed" status?

Comment: Similar to the `status` there's also a `result`; could that be overwritten to set the result to `failed`?

Answer (score 1):

The bash equivalent for @shayki-abramczyk 's script (thanks btw!)

```
- bash: |
    echo "Cancel all jobs..."

    url="${SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI}${SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID}/_apis/build/builds/${BUILD_BUILDID}?api-version=2.0"

    curl -X "PATCH" "$url" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}" \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -d $'{"status":"Cancelling"}'

  displayName: Cancel the pipeline
  condition: failed()
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

You will have to also go into your project settings in azure devops, Permissions, Groups, edit the Build Administrators group and then add the Project Collection Build Service (yourcompanyhere) user to it.

Also a quick note on Failed over Cancelled. According to the docs there is a "result" field which has a failed option, but the "status" field does not. I have tried many permutations of just updating one and not the other, but the status=cancelling one is the only reliable one and in no cases could I get it to show the build as "failed" :(

Docs for the build api update method are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Does this work for windows and ubuntu clients?